# Kie-Drools Workbench Deployment Error

Tags: tomcat, drools, kie, drools-kie-workbench

1. I have used **Wildify10** & kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war & kie-server-7.0.0.Final-ee7.war to deploy and use the KIE Workbench for Drools.
   When I start the wildify, it is unable to deploy both kie-drools-wb-7.0.0 & kie-server-7.0.0. It prompts as "Services Failed to start"...

**command line exception**

> service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.ext.security.server.CacheHeadersFilter".START
>   (missing) de pendents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.wa
>   r".deploymentCompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.ext.security.server.LoginRedirectServlet".START
>   (missing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.
>   war".deploymentCompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter".START
>   (missing) d ependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.w
>   ar".deploymentCompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter".START
>   (miss ing) dependents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildf
>   ly10.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.server.FileDownloadServlet".START (missing)
>   dependents: [s ervice
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".deploymen
>   tCompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.server.FileUploadServlet".START (missing)
>   dependents: [ser vice
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".deploymentC
>   ompleteService]
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".co
>   mponent."org.uberfire.server.locale.GWTLocaleHeaderFilter".START
>   (missing) depen dents: [service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".
>   deploymentCompleteService]
>         service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/kie-drools
>   -wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit.
>   "kie-drools-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war".deploymentCompleteService]
>   WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service
>   jboss.deployment.uni t."kie-server-7.0.0.Final-ee7.war".PARSE
>         service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/kie-drools
>   -wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10"

Help me resolve this issue if anyonw has ever faced it.

2. I have also tried deploying kie-drools-workbench with **Tomcat**. Now the workbench is deployed but it is not started in the browser. I cant't open the kie workbench in the browser.

Please help me to successfully deploy and run/access kie-drools-workbench using either of the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide detailed configuration information?

You can take a look on those steps

Install WildFly,Drools and Workbench:

```
1) Add WildFly bin folder to the Path enviroment variable
2) Add the admin user
3) Follow this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HUFaL--SwI
    First create and admin user
        1- in command type add-user
        2- press (a)
        3- type the user name
        4- type the password
        5- y y and for the last question say no
4) Now to WildFly/bin and open standalone.conf.bat and paste these following lines at the end of the file
    set SERVER_CONFIG=--server-config=standalone-full.xml
    set KIE_SERVER_USER=-Dorg.kie.server.user=kieserver
    set KIE_SERVER_PWD=-Dorg.kie.server.pwd=kieserver
    set KIE_CONTROLLER_USER=-Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=kieserver
    set KIE_CONTROLLER_PWD=-Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=kieserver
    set KIE_CONTROLLER_URL=http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10/rest/controller
    set KIE_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8080/kie-server-6.5.0.Final-ee7/services/rest/server
    set KIE_SERVER=-Dorg.kie.server.location=%KIE_SERVER_URL%
    set KIE_CONTROLLER=-Dorg.kie.server.controller=%KIE_CONTROLLER_URL%
    set KIE_SERVER_ID=-Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver
    set SERVER_OPTS=%SERVER_CONFIG% %KIE_SERVER_USER% %KIE_SERVER_PWD% %KIE_CONTROLLER_USER% %KIE_CONTROLLER_PWD% %KIE_SERVER% %KIE_CONTROLLER% %KIE_SERVER_ID%
5) Modify the JVM memory on the same file. For example: set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx1024M -XX:MetaspaceSize=196
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stanalonefull.xml instead of standalone.xml.